# AppleScript, simple GET request

Tags: get, applescript, xmlhttprequest

Im trying to rewrite something ive written in Visual Basic that uses an XMLHTTP 'GET' request. How do I do this in AppleScript? I can only seem to find information about 'POST' requests, which require input/output parameters but I want just the XML that going to this url should output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to just use curl: `do shell script "curl --get --data-urlencode q=" & quoted form of "whatever" & " http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0" without altering line endings`

- `without altering line endings` doesn't convert LF to CR or chomp the last newline
- `quoted form of "it's"` → `'it'\''s'`
- `curl --get` (`-G`) sends `--data` / `--data-binary` / `--data-urlencode` as a GET request instead of the default POST
- `curl --data-urlencode name=value` adds a percent-encoded parameter

If the parameters don't need to be escaped: `do shell script "curl http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=curl" without altering line endings`

Comment: Can you explain what each part is for? I just tried putting my url into where the 'http....v=1.0' part but it gave me an error saying: error "sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `0'

Comment: Ok ive got a Terminal command that does it using curl -sL -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n" "URL" -o /Downloads/

Ive tried putting this into an AppleScript with 'do shell script' but it seems to have an issue with either the "" marks or the % sign, how do i solve that? Or can I write a script that runs through terminal and just launch that instead?

Comment: @user1045280 I edited the answer... You need to backslash-escape double quotes and backslashes.